# Form input loses focus based on position

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm encountering a weird bug that is only occurring in the Android built in browser. I have a form input on my main page (input #1). When a user taps this form input I then show a white screen with another input at the top (input #2). I am using input #2 as an autocompleter. So when the user taps input #1 I am capturing that tap and I am doing a:

`$('#page2').show();
$('#input2').focus();`

This will correctly bring up the keyboard in Chrome on Android, Chrome on iOS, and Safari on iOS. However, when using the built in browser on Android I can see input #2 getting focus and then immediately losing it. I have determined the problem is that input #2 is laying directly on top of an image from my main page. If I take this image out it works as expected. Unfortunately I don't have that option. So I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas. I've created a jsfiddle that will reproduce the bug:

http://jsfiddle.net/yfnME/3/

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you cant hide the image right?

Comment: I've tried hiding it before the .show() and that still doesn't work.

Comment: well, i made some modifications on your example. you have two pages but one inside the other. The inner one has `display=none`, i removed that attribute. I've separated the pages into two, and added some code. check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yfnME/5/

Comment: I originally had done it this way. However, the changePage() seems to hide the keyboard for me. In a normal browser you can see that the field still has focus after the changePage(), but even in iOS you will see that the keyboard disappears. So unfortunately this won't work for me. Thanks for looking into it though.

Comment: after you `.focus()` use `.trigger('click')` to show the keyboard. Or remove `data-role=page` attribute from the `#mainQuickSearch` div, this might be the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/F2WqH/

Comment: the jsfiddle link you provided doesn't seem to work in the built in android browser. It's working in the other browsers though. I will try to remove the `data-role=page`. I just tried to do that real quick but it seems as though the position is all messed up in the android browser.